# Detecting Voice Recognition Activation

Tags: android, microphone, recording, voice-recognition

Alright, I have this app that runs as a service and takes audio samples every so often, and keeps track of the amplitude. It works beautifully. I have try/catch blocks so that my app doesn't interfere with other apps using the microphone, and all of that. The *only* problem I have is with the Voice Recognition app. Any other app that uses the microphone, recording memos, the phone, anything, doesn't bother my app because of the catch blocks. However, if the voice recognition app is running when my app tries to take its sample, my app crashes. To my knowledge, my app fails when it reaches the stop() function, for whatever reason...but that's not what I'm here for.

The thing I would like to know is if there is a way to detect if the Voice Recognition app is running/is started. Like I said, I have the catch blocks in place which work beautifully for every OTHER situation when the microphone wouldn't be accessible, but they, for some reason, don't work for the voice recognition.

Comment: I have not yet found the answer to this question, however I have found a way around it. I added another try/catch block, which checked for microphone input errors, and if it failed than it closes the instance of MediaRecorder and starts over. Works like a charm! However, if anyone knows the answer to the question above feel free to answer it!

Comment: Awesome. If its not an IP thing, can you share the code? It will help a lot of people to understand the basics of how to implement a voice recognition system. Thnx!

Comment: If I could provide it, I would. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the code I used. As for the real, REAL basics, I know that the voice recognition acts more like a digital 'phone call' and the recognizing itself is actually done by Google on their servers, not the phone. When the app starts, it streams your voice to the servers, which then send back the text (or command) that they think you said. Sorry I can't be much more help.